# php how to decect if wget faced 404 error?

Tags: php, wget

I'm running wget through php's shell_exec()
How could I understand that wget got 404 error getting file?

Thank you.

Comment: Why aren't you using something that gives you a proper PHP API? http://php.net/curl

Comment: David, this should be an answer.

Comment: @David, I credited you in my answer as you raised the WTF first. The OP is solving the wrong problem. Still, I had the same reaction, so I answered. I would have just as happily up-voted your's.

Comment: I don't like answers that don't answer the question. I'm happy to include "But you should do this instead" as an addendum to something that actually answers the question, but not as something that stands alone.

Comment: I've decided to use wget because I need to download big video files (more than memory allowed for php). Maybe CURL could save directly to file, but I don't thin it could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/wget@sunsite.dk/msg07254.html), when faced with a simple "download file XYZ" operation, wget will return a return code of 1 when the download fails for some reason. It won't work for complex operations like mirroring a site, but in your case, it should be fine.

You can get hold of the return code using [**exec()**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)`s "return_var" variable.

Wget should return `1` (or some other status code that is not `0`) if it is presented with a proper 404 page. Try it out.

To actually distinguish the exact error status code that wget receives, I think you'll have to start parsing its output (or use a PHP-based web client class.)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are solving the wrong problem. Please try [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) before using anything that can't fail portably with a meaningful, parse-able status as [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19068/david-dorward) first suggested in comments.

Comment: @Downvoters: Care to explain your vote? Is it my fault that the OP added more info and I wasn't clicking refresh once a second so I could see it and adjust my answer? Can programmers not read timestamps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a command line like the following with `exec`:

```
exec("wget http://www.google.com/not_present.html 2> some_temp_file ",&output,&retvalue);
```

Check the `retvalue` to see if an error has occurred. A non-zero value means error occurred. Since we've redirected the standard error to `some_temp_file`, you can grep this file for the pattern `404 Not Found`. If present it indicates that a `404` has occurred.